# Xen cannot see all the LUNs in ISCSI HP StorageWorks MSA2312i Dual Controller Modular Smart Array

Tags: xen, hp, iscsi, citrix, lun

I have a HP StorageWorks MSA2312i Dual Controller Modular Smart Array
and a second enclosure.

I have four vdisks:

- vd01 (RAID5)  (Current Owner A)
- vd02 (RAID5)  (Current Owner B)
- vd03 (RAID10) (Current Owner A)
- vd04 (RAID10) (Current Owner B)

With two volumes per vdisk (vd01_001, vd01_v002 and so on)

The problem is that while Xen can see all the volumes in vd01 and vd02
(whose main controllers are A and B respectively), Xen cannot see any
other volumes from vd03 and vd04.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
[The complete log of a full conection from XenCenter](https://gist.github.com/alexsaezm/f1d1f91dca546120561f)

EDIT2:
If I add the disks of the second enclosure to a vdisk with disks of the first enclosure, I can see the new space, as workaround.

Comment: you're going to have to add a lot more detail to the actual problem here; logs etc?

Comment: Ups! Logs added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found without any explanation, the solution.

The vdisk need to start with 00.

vd00, vd01, vd02 and vd03 just works.